# Select field is not showing the dropdown values

Tags: javascript, ajax, mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel

Can anyone please help me, I am stuck with this past two days. I am new to Knockoutjs / viewmodel. I am trying to understand how bind the data to the dropdownlist. The dropdown values needs to be pulled from the DB through the API depending on the value entered in another field (which is basically the input parameter for the API to return the dropdown values). The API to return the data is like below

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetGInfo(string sNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            DSRepository dsr = new DSRepository();
            List<String> gTypeList = dsr.GetDDInfo(sNumber);
            if (gTypeList != null)
                return Json(gTypeList);
            else
                return null;    
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }}
```

Below are the two fields

```
 // this value should be passed in to the API to retrieve the dropdown list 
 self.sNumber= ko.observable().extend({ required: { params: true, message: "Required!" } }); 
 //Dropdown list field 
 self.gType= ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

  //function for making a call to the API 
  self.getGTypes = function (data, event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/REQ/GetGInfo',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            sNumber: self.sNumber()
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.length < 1)
                console.log("Record retrieved successfully");
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error retrieving the record");
        }
    })
   };
```

And UI is like below

```
<div class="form-group required">
<label for="SNumber" class="control-label">SNumber:</label>
<input type="number" id="SNumber" class="form-control" data-bind="event: {change: getGTypes}, value: sNumber">
</div>

<div class="form-group required">
<label for="GType" class="control-label">GType</label>
<select id="GType" name="GType" class="form-control" data-bind="options: getGTypes, value: gType, optionsCaption: 'Select'"></select>
</div>
</div>
```

So when the value is entered in the SNumber field the `getGenoTypes` is called I see that the data is returned from the API through the debugging, for the number I entered I see that below data `gTypeList` is returned back from API

[image]

But in the dropdown I see nothing

[image]

Please help me what is that I am missing here totally stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually *save* the dropdown values that you receive from the API on your viewmodel. You can't just execute the API call and expect Knockout to magically understand it needs to use the (asynchronous) response data to populate the select list.

So basically, you need to do something like this:

```
// this value should be passed in to the API to retrieve the dropdown list 
self.sNumber = ko.observable().extend({ required: { params: true, message: "Required!" } }); 
//Dropdown list field 
self.gType = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
// Dropdown list values
self.gTypes = ko.observableArray();

//function for making a call to the API 
self.getGTypes = function (data, event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/REQ/GetGInfo',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            sNumber: self.sNumber()
        },
        success: function (response) {
            self.gTypes(response);
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error retrieving the record");
        }
    })
}; 

<select id="GType" name="GType" class="form-control" data-bind="
    options: gTypes,
    value: gType,
    optionsCaption: 'Select'"></select>
```

Note that I don't know what `response` looks like so this is probably not 100% correct, but I hope you get the idea of it.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I have been stuck with this past two days. Didnt realize that I am missing something like this orgeting to store the response